# Не удается вызвать переопределенный защищенный метод

Tags: c++, virtual, protected

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Interface
{
protected:

  virtual void Protected() const = 0;

};

class Implementation : public Interface
{
public:

  void Public(const Interface& interface)
  {
    interface.Protected();
  }

protected:

  void Protected() const override
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

При попытке собрать такой код, компилятор говорит мне, что я неправ, и мне нельзя давать доступ к методу `Protected()`. Мне кажется это странным. Хочу понять, почему такое делать нельзя.

Comment: Я наверное что-то не пониманию, но что тут странного? Вы хотите получить доступ к protected функции из другого класса.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обратиться не к унаследованному члену, а к члену переданного в качестве аргумента объекту. А к нему может обращаться только его наследник. Но в вашем случае `this`, грубо говоря, наследником `interface` не является :) - это посторонний объект. А вот так -       `Interface::Protected();` - вам никто не помешает обратиться.

Comment: @Harry, мне не совсем понятно.

Comment: Насколько я помню, я всегда и без проблем обращался даже к закрытым членам аргумента в, например, том же операторе копирующего присваивания, и никаких проблем с этим не было.